# Define a variable in a function php

Tags: php

I have a function as below but I get warning for `$tab` variable that says it is not defined. How can I define it and not receive this warning anymore?

```
<?php
/*** suggested articles as random ***/

function doArticle_suggested_small_horizontall($articleid,$title,$photo,$parentid,$catid,$altdescription) {

    $tab .= "<table  width=150 cellspacing=5 style=border: 1px solid #0066ff align=right>\n";
    $tab .= "<tr>\n";
    $tab .= "<td  align=center bgcolor=#ffffff><a href='../artandculture/adetails.php?articleid=$articleid&parentid=$parentid&catid=$catid'>
    <img src='../images/simage/$photo' border='0' alt='$altdescription'></a></td>\n";
    $tab .= "</tr>\n";  
    $tab .= "<tr  align=right width=150 height=80 border=0 style=border: 1px solid #ffffff>\n";
    $tab .= "<td width=110 align=right dir='rtl' border=0 style=border: 1px solid #ffffff ><p class=articletitlenounderline><a href='../artandculture/adetails.php?articleid=$articleid&parentid=$parentid&catid=$catid'><strong>$title </strong></p></a></td>\n";
    $tab .= "</tr>\n";
    $tab .= "</table> <p> <hr class='hr99' ></hr></p>";
    return $tab;
}
$tab = "";
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to define `$tab` at the beginning of the function.

replace `$tab .= "<table  width=15 ....`

with `$tab = "<table  width=15....`

Or you could just add `$tab = "";` as the first line of the function, now you are defining it outside the function which you should remove.

Comment: It is defined in the first line.  (you need to remove the `.` for concatonation)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Define `$tab`,

```
$tab = [...];
```

Then you need to do **.=** on the variable. The variable does not exist where you start using it.

Answer (score 0):

".=" is telling PHP to add a string to an existing variable. PHP cannot add the string if there is no existing variable.

```
// Add this before your first $tab .=
$tab = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `$tab` to the start of the function in order for the concatenation to properly work:

Instead of this in the end:
    $tab = "";

Do this:

```
  <?php
  /////////////////////suggested articles as random /////////////////////////

     function doArticle_suggested_small_horizontall($articleid,$title,$photo,$parentid,$catid,$altdescription) {
       $tab = "";
       $tab .= "<table  width=150 cellspacing=5 style=border: 1px solid #0066ff align=right>\n";
        $tab .= "<tr>\n";
        $tab .= "<td  align=center bgcolor=#ffffff><a href='../artandculture/adetails.php?articleid=$articleid&parentid=$parentid&catid=$catid'>
        <img src='../images/simage/$photo' border='0' alt='$altdescription'></a></td>\n";
        $tab .= "</tr>\n";  
        $tab .= "<tr  align=right width=150 height=80 border=0 style=border: 1px solid #ffffff>\n";
        $tab .= "<td width=110 align=right dir='rtl' border=0 style=border: 1px solid #ffffff ><p class=articletitlenounderline><a href='../artandculture/adetails.php?articleid=$articleid&parentid=$parentid&catid=$catid'><strong>$title </strong></p></a></td>\n";
        $tab .= "</tr>\n";
        $tab .= "</table> <p> <hr class='hr99' ></hr></p>";
        return $tab;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, if you already have something assigned to $tab and want to append it from function, you must either send it in as an argument to the function or add the function output

```
function example( $tab, $something = false ) {
  $tab .= ', added this in example function';
  return $tab;
}

$tab = 'Original content';
echo example( $tab ); // Output: Original content, added this in example function

function example2( $something = false ) {
  return ', added this in example2 function';
}

$tab = 'Original content 2';
$tab .= example2();
echo $tab: // Output: Original content 2, added this in example2 function
```